# Unity - Простое взаимодействие между предметами

Tags: unity3d

День добрый друзья. Есть простая задачка, хочу что бы персонаж поднимал предмет, подходил к другому объекту и использовал поднятый предмет через катсцену. Без инвентаря. Я сделал триггерный скрипт который поднимает предмет, такой же скрипт который применяет предмет, но как сделать проверку что был игра проверила поднимал ли я этот предмет и включала скрипт?

Comment: Когда игрок поднимает предмет, вы же сохраняете, какой предмет он поднял? А объект, который игрок может использовать, знает, какой предмет у него должен быть для этого в руке. Почему бы просто не сравнить? Можно сделать перечисление enum всех предметов, которые можно поднять, или отдельный ScriptableObject для кажддого поднимаемого объекта

Answer (score 0):

```
bool get;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.name == "chery" && get == false) //замените "chery" на название своего объекта, откуда вы берёте предмет
    {
        get = true;
        //ваш код, что надо сделать если "подняли"
    }
    else if (collision.collider.name == "bush" && get == true) //замените "bush" на название своего объекта, куда вы хотите положить предмет
    {
        get = false;
        //код, что надо сделать, если вы положили предмет (анимация например)
    }
}
```

Вроде как-то так